# mod_rewrite issue in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, backend

Setting

```
'RewriteBase /'
```

on production site and

```
'RewriteBase /mysitefolder'
```

on development site solved this, hope this helps another guy.

---

I have a big issue with modRewrite and Codeigniter, and I have these rewrite rules:

```
### GO TO GODPANEL

RewriteRule ^/godpanel$ /panel/godpanel [L]
```

I can't make this rule rewrite my page in this way:

`myhosting.com/godpanel`

to

`myhosting.com/panel/godpanel`

It keeps saying this pages doesn't exist. I can't make other rules to work properly,
the only rule that works is the original that rewrites the `index.php`

```
# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(start(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope you can understand me.  Thanks!

(EDITED)

Well something changed since yesterday,
when I point to localhost/mysite.com/mycontroller it works,
now when i poin to localhost/mysite.com/godpanel
the url changes to localhost/panel/godpanel

seems that the rules is apllying but in a wrong way

im so noob with regexp in mod rewrite files :(

heres my entire file

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    ### GO TO GODPANEL

    RewriteRule ^godpanel$ /weird/stuff [R=301,L]

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(start(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the godpanel rule placed above your index.php rules?

Comment: yeah it is on the top of others

Comment: It's kind of you to mark the question as solved in the title, but that's not the expected way on StackOverflow. If your problem was solved by an answer, please mark that answer as "Accepted" (with the checkmark besides the answer). Or if you found a solution on your own, consider posting an answer with your solution (and mark it as Accepted), so that your solution can help other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the godpanel rule is above all your other rules.

Secondly try removing the forward slash from the start of the `^/godpanel` part of your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^godpanel$ /panel/godpanel [R=301,L]
```

Comment: when I point to localhost/mysite.com/mycontroller it works, now when i point to localhost/mysite.com/godpanel the url changes to localhost/panel/godpanel its working but in the wrong way

Comment: wait... your url is `localhost/mysite.com/mycontroller`?

Comment: yeah i figured out the problem, you MUST specify the RewriteBase to '/' in my production site and '/mysitefolder' in my development. Anyway thanks to everyone, you helped me to notice my mistake.